# CSS3 horizontal resize in both ways

Tags: html, css, resize

it's posible to use CSS3 resize property (horizontal) to resize to both ways (left and right)?

I'm trying to use direction: rtl, but it not working.

Thanks.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_resize.asp

Comment: I don't think so, it's either resize: horizontal but then the div has to be centered. Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/DRFTp/

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I need to resize element to left OR to right side. Not both in one time.

Comment: You could use javascript/a library to do such a thing but I am pretty sure it's not possible in pure CSS